# ROO: Custom Finders - find by Primary Key?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-roo

I generated an entity and called "finder list" command.

All finders listed but primary key finders not listed .. 
My primary key's type is timestamp. I need "findDatebyBetween" custom finder.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your own query to the repository interface.  That is, assuming your Domain object is Yada

```
@Query("select y from Yada y where y.date >= ?1 AND y.date <= ?2")
public List<Yada> findDatebyBetween(Date start, Date end);
```

You don't need to add any implementation, roo will figure it out.